# How to stop title attribute from displaying tooltip temporarily?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a popup div showing on rightclick (I know this breaks expected functionality but Google Docs does it so why not?) However the element I'm showing my popup on has a "title" attribute set which appears over the top of my div. I still want the tooltip to work but not when the popup is there.

What's the best way to stop the tooltip showing while the popup is open/openning?

Edit: I am using jQuery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [jquery](http://jquery.com) you could bind the hover function to also set the title attribute to blank onmouseover and then reset it on mouse out.

```
$("element#id").hover(
 function() {
  $(this).attr("title","");
  $("div#popout").show();
 },
 function() {
  $("div#popout").hide();
  $(this).attr("title",originalTitle);
 }
);
```

Comment: nice! I am using jQuery so perfect (should have mentioned that)

Comment: Where is originalTitle coming from? You could store it using .data() for a more general solution.

Comment: how does the tooltip still work on hover in this solution, whilst enabling rightclick for popup?

Answer (score 3):

Here is another example of how it can be done by using [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) for value storage and [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) for value assigning

```
$('[title]').on({
    mouseenter : function()
    {
        $(this).data('title', this.title).prop('title', '');
    },
    mouseleave: function()
    {
        $(this).prop('title', $(this).data('title'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, I didn't care what the content of the title tag was. I just did:

```
$('a').hover(function() {

    $(this).attr('title', '');

});
```

Which stopped the title tag from showing.

Answer (score 0):

I think setting to blank space and when the popup closes, setting again the proper text. I think this is the easiest way to stop it.