# Can removing the title attribute with jQuery have a negative effect?

Tags: jquery, tooltip, title

Im a complete jQuery noob, so forgive me if this is a stupid question.

Will this code have a negative effect on my site? Im thinking SEO and so on.

```
$(function() {
  $("[title]").removeAttr('title');
});
```

Im using it to prevent the tooltip from popping up when the mouse is hovered on an image.

I looked in here and found this code also:

```
$(this).data("title", $(this).attr("title")).removeAttr("title");
```

But I can't get that to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you trying to remove the title?

Comment: @Orbling "Im using it to prevent the tooltip from popping up when the mouse is hovered on an image."

Comment: @lasseespeholt: In which case you want this question: [How to stop title attribute from displaying tooltip temporarily?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287407/how-to-stop-title-attribute-from-displaying-tooltip-temporarily)

Comment: @Orbling No, I was answering your question for him. His question is entirely different from yours. He know the technique (your link) but didn't know the consequences which he was asking for.

Comment: @lasseespeholt: Good point, totally didn't look at the right place there!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing you do in jQuery will have an effect on SEO, as it happens **client-side**, search engines (Google, et al.) will never see changes made in Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :) Guess I'll just remove the title of everything on the page using the first jQuery example then.